# Why some apps appear in english?

Tags: language-support

I live in Chile and here we speak spanish.

All my system is set to spanish (even the fact that I don't have any problem with english, Thanks God!).

But... I wonder... Why some apps (games and others) I installed with the Ubuntu Software Center appear in english in this PC, but are in spanish in my laptop PC?

Can I fix it? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all applications have been internationalized, or not translated in Spanish yet.  As many (most) applications are built in English, this becomes the default language.

If the application has been built following the [internationalizing you application](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials/internationalizing-your-app/) guidelines, you can build a Spanish message bundle for the application.  The [Ubuntu Internationalization Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation) provides more details.  Providing your translations will help the general community.

Some applications provide message bundles as a separate package.  These applications are likely to using English unless you install the appropriate internationalization package.